# Message displaying below the popup

Tags: discussion, bug, design

I am not sure about this bug. While i was reviewing closed votes, some error messages ware displayed below the pop-up as shown in the image [image]. Later i checked when it appears. unfortunately it will shown when i **double click** on the close button for marking pa post as closed.

Ignore this question if it is not a bug.